# Effect of shielding on a miniature Helmholtz coil

Tags: electromagnetism, experimental-physics, magnetic-fields

So a bit of background... I'm a university graduate student with primarily digital signal processing and embedded experience. However I've managed to get myself involved with a project that requires me to characterize and tune a series of magnetically sensitive devices. I understand the basic theory of electomagnetics, but have never worked out complex magnetic analysis or used any of the standard simulation tools. Long story short, I'm completely out of my league! (At least until I get the things characterized, then I get to do some fun/nasty DSP feedback and filtering.)

Unfortunately the existing experimental setup I inherited from my predecessor is, well... lackluster. The field strengths that I will be working with are in the range of nano-Tesla and the devices are influenced by fields into the pico-Tesla range. I'm getting awful results and I can't tell if it's due to the devices being awful (probably) or just the experimental setup. Currently I have a sloppily wound coil of magnet wire in series with a 50 Ohm resistor, driven by an ordinary signal generator with P2P voltages correlated with field strength by an excel graph. The experiment sits under a copper-foil taped together box of high-permeability metal sheets. Never mind that the adhesive on the copper foil tape isn't very conductive and there is a few kOhm between the panels.

My plan is to replace the mess with a cylindrical shield, Helmholtz coil and an actual coil driver with active feedback.

**Ok rant over I promise! Here are the actual questions that I need help with.**

I was told that that small Helmholtz coils can't produce a consistent magnetic field within their centers. I don't understand why the diameter would have a lower limit, and would think the same characteristics would hold regardless. Granted I can understand the susceptibility of the system to outside fields could decrease as it gets smaller.
Is this true, or just someone trying to tell me that a miniature coil sized for the application sounds like a dumb idea?

Secondly and probably more difficult to answer, I've made a cylindrical shield by soldering together some larger scraps of high-permeability metal sheeting. I would like to place the miniature Helmholtz coil within it. I've been told that putting a high-permeability shield near a coil affects its radiation pattern, (makes sense) my question is how small an air gap between the coil and wall of the shield can I have without ruining the field within the center?

I would model and simulate the thing, and I'm attempting to learn how to do so, but I would like a few opinions of people who actually understand this stuff. :-)
The shield I was able to make is 9.3 cm in diameter and 13 cm tall. The Helmholtz would be wound on 3/16" thick acrylic rings from 24-26AWG magnet wire. My target magnetic field strengths are between micro-Tesla and nano-Tesla.
Currently I was planning for a coil of 5 cm diameter which gives me 2 cm air-gap all around, but if I can make it bigger that would be great. (smaller is ok as well)

---Edit---
Here's a graphic I threw together showing the shield and coil. (Dimensioned portion not to scale with isometric.)
[image: Shield and Helmholtz coil assembly]

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stackexchange. Several comments: This is a lot of text. The experimental setup is (at least to me) not completely clear, maybe a picture would help? On the other hand, a few of your questions seem rather specific (like "I was told that small Helmholtz coils can't produce a consistent magnetic field within their centers. Is that true?"), so it might be better to ask one question at a time and limit the background to that question. Also, it might be worth posting one or the other question over at http://electronics.stackexchange.com/ if you don't get answers here.

Comment: It really depends on what you want to do. The naive Helmholtz coil is usually not a good idea, as it has a really small region with a homogeneous field and putting a high permeability shield around this will completely destroy that. You are basically shooting yourself in the foot here. Ultralow magnetic fields (do you _really_ need that?) are hard and require large shielding chambers and triple Helmholtz coils to compensate for Earth's field. The mu-metal shields have to be annealed and treated like eggs... if you have soldered these things, you have basically destroyed the metal, already.

Comment: "if you have soldered these things, you have basically destroyed the metal" The manufacturer suggests soldering if you can't use heliarc welding to form things, the sheeting is already stress annealed.

Comment: Unfortunately I do have to deal with the ultralow fields, that isn't something I have a choice of changing. Luckily I'm not trying to cancel out the earth's magnetic field, the Helmholtz coil is for exciting the devices, while the shield hopefully removes some of the random magnetic junk generated from the surrounding equipment.

Comment: Would a solenoid design be more appropriate? It's just that it will be a pain to move things in/out of it.